# Dynamic programming problem and optimal solution

Tags: dynamic-programming

> For the following problem
>   \begin{equation}\max_{(\tilde{c}_t,\tilde{a}_{t+1+s})}\sum_{s=0}^{\infty}\beta ^su(\tilde{c}_{t+s})\end{equation}
>
> s.t. the following restrictions
>
> $\begin{equation}
> \begin{split}
> \tilde{c}_t&=(1-\delta )Y_t+a_t-\frac{\tilde{a}_{t+1}}{R_t}\\
> \tilde{c}_{t+1+s}&=(1-\delta )Y_{t+1+s}^{e}+\tilde{a}_{t+1+s}-\frac{\tilde{a}_{t+2+s}}{R_{t+1+s}}, \forall s \geq 0
> \end{split}
> \end{equation}$
>
> where:
>
> $\tilde{c}_t$: Consumption at time $t$
>
> $\tilde{a}_t$: Financial wealth at time $t$
>
> $Y_t$: Income at time $t$
>
> $R_t$: Nominal interest rate at time $t$
>
> $Y_t^e$: Expected income at time $t$
>
> Consider that $u(\tilde{c}_{t+s})$ is defined by the isoelastic utility function: $u(\tilde{c}_{t+s})=\frac{\tilde{c}_{t+s}^{1-\frac{1}{\sigma}}-1}{1-\frac{1}{\sigma}}$
>
> Find the optimal policy function for $\tilde{c}_t$.

I guess the natural procedure is first forming the lagrangian

$\begin{equation}
L=\sum_{s=0}^{\infty}\beta ^s\frac{\tilde{c}_{t+s}^{1-\frac{1}{\sigma}}-1}{1-\frac{1}{\sigma}}+\sum_{t=0}^{\infty}\lambda _t \left [ \tilde{c}_t- (1-\delta )Y_t-a_t+\frac{\tilde{a}_{t+1}}{R_t} \right ]+\sum_{t=0}^{\infty}\pi _t\left [ \tilde{c}_{t+1+s}-(1-\delta )Y_{t+1+s}^{e}-\tilde{a}_{t+1+s}+\frac{\tilde{a}_{t+2+s}}{R_{t+1+s}} \right ]
\end{equation}$

but then, what would be the FOC? these?

$\begin{equation}
\frac{\partial L}{\partial \tilde{c}_{t}}=\frac{\partial L}{\partial \tilde{c}_{t+s}}=\frac{\partial L}{\partial \tilde{a}_{t+1+s}}=\frac{\partial L}{\partial \tilde{a}_{t+2+s}}=0
\end{equation}$

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: Since the problem is stationary, it may be easier to approach it using the Bellman equation.

Comment: Thanks! How could I write the Bellman equation if I had two restrictions like this problem or will I have two bellman equations?